# How to make rootless containers with Podman efficient

Tags: containers, podman

I launched web applications in containers with the help of `podman` and there was a performance problem if I run container as rootless user. I have to wait a few seconds for the page to load.
The application uses the `postgres` database.
When I run the containers as root, the application runs much faster.
There is some way to improve the performance of the rootless containers?

podman info:

```
 host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.21.3
  cgroupControllers: []
  cgroupManager: cgroupfs
  cgroupVersion: v1
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.0.29-1.module_el8.4.0+886+c9a8d9ad.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.29, commit: 97bba1e91aaab5be2e93bacd34ec4e66655a02ae'
  cpus: 4
  distribution:
    distribution: '"centos"'
    version: "8"
  eventLogger: file
  hostname: localhost
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 5002
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 5002
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
  kernel: 4.18.0-305.12.1.el8_4.x86_64
  linkmode: dynamic
  memFree: 134930432
  memTotal: 8145588224
  ociRuntime:
    name: runc
    package: runc-1.0.0-74.rc95.module_el8.4.0+886+c9a8d9ad.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: |-
      runc version spec: 1.0.2-dev
      go: go1.15.14
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    path: /run/user/5002/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: true
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.1.8-1.module_el8.4.0+641+6116a774.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.1.8
      commit: d361001f495417b880f20329121e3aa431a8f90f
      libslirp: 4.3.1
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  swapFree: 2139840512
  swapTotal: 2147479552
  uptime: 2h 58m 15.4s (Approximately 0.08 days)
registries:
  search:
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - registry.redhat.io
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /home/user/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 0
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions:
    overlay.mount_program:
      Executable: /usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs
      Package: fuse-overlayfs-1.6-1.module_el8.4.0+886+c9a8d9ad.x86_64
      Version: |-
        fusermount3 version: 3.2.1
        fuse-overlayfs: version 1.6
        FUSE library version 3.2.1
        using FUSE kernel interface version 7.26
  graphRoot: /home/admin/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageStore:
    number: 0
  runRoot: /run/user/5002/containers
  volumePath: /home/user/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 3.2.3
  Built: 1632432139
  BuiltTime: Thu Sep 23 23:22:19 2021
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.15.14
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 3.2.3
```

Comment: If you are using  _fuse-overlayfs_, you might want to instead use native overlayfs because it's faster. Support for using native overlayfs as an unprivileged user is available for Podman version >= 3.1 on a Linux kernel version >= 5.12